# stacked rectangles not moving properly

Tags: java

So i was given starter code for a project, basicly homework for a java class i'm in, but can't seem to get the solution quite correct. The basic idea is; there are a stack of rectangles in a graphics display and each rectangle is clickable. if you click a rectangle somewhere below the top one, the one you clicked would be brought to the top. a check would be made to make sure this would only happen if you clicked that box only, and only if you clicked the visible part of that box.

this is the section of code in question, the part i was supposed to add:

```
public void moveToTop( Point p ) {
    int movingRectangle = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i > rects.size(); i++) {
        if(isInside(rects.get(i), p)) {
            movingRectangle = i;
        }
    }
    if(movingRectangle >= 0) {
        addRect(deleteRect(movingRectangle));
    }
}
private boolean isInside(Rectangle143 r, Point p) {
    return r.getX() <= p.getX()
        && p.getX() <= r.getX() + r.getWidth()
        && r.getY() <= p.getY()
        && p.getY() <= r.getY() + r.getHeight();
}
```

My problem is that the boxes aren't coming to the top like that should. they are clickable and show the location where i clicked, but nothing comes to the front.

I hope i asked this question so it's easy to understand.. if not.. let me know what i left out and i will try my best to fill any gaps.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you call your class "Rectangle143"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple bug in your for loop...

```
for(int i = 0; i > rects.size(); i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
```

Note the change from > to <

Comment: lol, this is me, missing the simplest things. now my next question is, is there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: You could break out of the loop once you've found the rectangle to move. That would mean it doesn't keep searching the rest of them.